# Links to friends on Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to get all the friends of the logged in user and then display them. Each "friend" is listed as a hyperlink. However when I hit the hyperlink nothing happens. I am only prompted with a Facebook logo and when I hit that then I am redirected to the profile. Is it even the correct way of doing it? Atleast the code prints the friends name and id correctly.

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
$friends = $friends['data'];

foreach($friends as $friend) {
    echo "<a href='http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=".$friend['id']."'>".$friend['name']."</a><br />";
}
```

And I have this in the index file in the folder of the canvas url.

```
<?php if ($user): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
<?php else: ?>
    <script>top.location.href = "<?php echo $loginUrl ?>"</script>
<?php endif ?>
```

When I go the the application on Facebook and I am not logged in I am prompt to login, when I do so I am redirected to the url where the app is hosted, but it is not inside the iframe in Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you can't have an application or tab iFrame containing a page from the Facebook domain. You need to break out of the iFrame to display the friends profile - the easiest way for you would be to specify a target attribute with your links.

```
foreach($friends as $friend) {
    echo "<a target='_top' href='http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=".$friend['id']."'>".$friend['name']."</a><br />";
}
```

---

To answer the second part of your question, you need to specify a redirect URI with your login:

```
<?php
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
  array(
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://apps.facebok.com/yourapp/'
  )
);
?>
```